# ListedColorMap for coloring Well Log Composite

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib, colors

From data i have, there are GR, RHOB, Lithology(LITH), and Drill stem zone. I've made code to give color on my log lithology and Drill stem zone, but for Drill stem zone there is no color appear and for the lithology log the color that appear so random. the data have been checked and there is no problem for the value, but when i want show it from my coding, data that already labeled with color did not match. is there any solution for me to **give match color for my composite log**?

```
data = `np.loadtxt(file, skiprows=2243, max_rows=1498)`
mnemonics = ['Depth', 'DT', 'S-Wave', 'CALI', 'GR', "RHOB", 'RT', 'SP', 'NPHI', 'DST_Zone', 'LITH', 'GNORM']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=mnemonics)
df.to_csv('well3.csv',index=False)`your text`
data = df[['Depth', 'GR', 'RT', 'RHOB', 'NPHI', 'DST_Zone','LITH']].values
depth = data[:,0]
Lith = data[:,-1]
Dst = data[:,-2]


rows, cols = 1,7
fig,ax = plt.subplots(nrows=rows, ncols=cols, figsize=(12, 10), sharey=True)
mnemonics = ['depth', 'GR', 'RT', 'RHOB', 'NPHI', 'DST_Zone','LITH']

for i in range (cols):
    if i < cols -1:
        ax[i].plot(data[:, i], data[:, 0], linewidth='0.5')
        ax[i].minorticks_on()
        ax[i].grid(which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='0.5', color='black')
        ax[i].grid(which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='0.5', color='yellow')
        ax[i].set_title('%s' % mnemonics[i])
        ax[i].set_ylim(max(depth), min(depth))
    elif i == cols -1:
        Lith_labels = Lith
        color_map = {0:'green',1: 'yellow', 2: 'grey', 3: '``your text``black'}
        colors1 = [color_map[int(label)] for label in Lith_labels]
        cmap1 = ListedColormap(colors1)
        F = np.vstack((Lith_labels,Lith_labels)).T
        ax[i].imshow(F, cmap=cmap1, aspect = 'auto', extent = [0, 1, max(data[:, 0]), min(data[:, 0])])
    elif i == cols -2:
        DST_labels = Dst
        color_maps = {0: 'grey', 1: 'red'}
        colors2 =  ['red' if label > 0 else 'grey' for label in DST_labels]
        cmap2 = ListedColormap(colors2)
        G = np.vstack((DST_labels,DST_labels)).T
        ax[i].imshow(G, cmap=cmap2, aspect = 'auto', extent = [0, 1, max(data[:, 0]), min(data[:, 0])])

ax[1].set_xlim(50, 250)
ax[2].set_xlim(0.1, 100)
ax[3].set_xlim(1.4, 2.7)
ax[4].set_xlim (0.6, 0)
ax[5].set_xlim(None)
ax[6].set_title('Lith')

y2 = data[:, 1]
y1 = y2*0+150
ax[1].fill_betweenx(data[:, 0], y1,y2, where=(y1>=y2), color='gold', linewidth=0)
ax[1].fill_betweenx(data[:, 0], y1,y2, where=(y1< y2), color='lime', linewidth=0)

plt.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
plt.show()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kjcl6.png)

i want to make color for log composite is match with the data, and for drill stem zone i want to show the color

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.